# While looping not accepting my entered key - Java AWT

Tags: java, multithreading, while-loop, awt

I am using a while loop in my method

```
public void keyTyped (KeyEvent e)
```

The problem here is that, the program enters the loop, it asks the user for input. And if the input is within the parameters, set by "while", it just keeps on repeating that input infinitely. It doesn't ask for another input again though I did put in the code for it to do so.

What I need is for it to ask the user for input each time it loops. Any help?

```
//cardChosen1 is "null" at this point`
            while (cardChosen1 < 97  || cardChosen1 > 108)
            {

                Thread.currentThread ().setPriority (Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
                cardChosen1 = e.getKeyChar ();
                System.out.println ("Inside Loop" + cardChosen1);

                repaint ();
                try
                {
                    // Stop thread for 20 milliseconds
                    Thread.sleep (20);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException ex)
                {
                    // do nothing
                }
                Thread.currentThread ().setPriority (Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
            }
```

Comment: Where is it asking for another input? The value of `e.getKeyChar()` won't change.

Comment: that's not how you create a while loop for an event based input... you need to have a main loop, where you check if key was pressed at all... and if it was pressed, then you check which one it was and take it into consideration for a valid user input. but you probably don't even need a while loop

Comment: @Ubica but I need it to keep on asking until the user has inputted the correct key.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard I am asking for another input, for when the entered input is not a valid input.

Comment: look, first time the program starts, ask the user for the input... on KeyPress you will get an event, which can check which key it was, if it is valid etc. and when you do all the code for that event, add another question... if it's only when the input is not valid, do `if(valid){//some code}else{//ask again}`

Comment: Start by taking a look at [Event Dispatching Thread](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_dispatching_thread) and [How to write KeyListeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html).  AWT, like most GUI frameworks, is a Event Driven environment, that is, you don't use a "loop" to wait for something to happen, you register a listener that is notified when some event occurs, then you take action.

Comment: @Ubica but the problem is how would I check its validity ?
With an if statement ?

Comment: read what MadProgrammer linked you... you will understand better what's going on when you press a Key

Comment: @Ubica While technically correct, it sounds more like your suggesting that the OP needs a second loop, when they need to understand what the Event Dispatching Thread is and how to respond to events within a GUI framework - just saying ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yes, I understand that. But he also needs to build on the logic he already has, and it's flawed.

Comment: @HassanAhmed yes... use an `if` statement, not while loop

Answer (score 1):

AWT, like most GUI frameworks, is event driven.  That is, you register some kind of callback/observer/listener with the API and wait for that callback/observer/listener to be notified that something has happened.

You have to remember that a GUI is not a linear progress of code, but instead, events can occur at any time in any sequence and you need to code for those occurrences.

Start by taking a look at [Event Dispatching Thread](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_dispatching_thread) to understand the core mechanism by which events are generated and notification is made within an AWT based framework.

Then take a look at [How to write KeyListeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html) to find out how you get notified of key events within your program.

Without more details about what you are trying to achieve, it's difficult to provide more information, but essentially, NEVER block the EDT, this will prevent it from process new events in the event queue and make it look like your program has hung (because it essentially has)

Answer (score 0):

This would be a good way to handle the event:

```
    addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent event) {
            cardChosen1 = event.getKeyChar();
            if(cardChosen1 > 97  && cardChosen1 < 108){
                // do something about the chosen card
            }else{
                // ask user to do something else
                // or press the key in a valid range
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {}
        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}
    });
```